Showing the identity log($z^n$) = n log (z) for a particular value of n and z
I was asked to show $\log(z^n) = n \log (z)$ where $z = 1 + i$ and $n = 5$.
The worked solutions state that they are not equal for those values but I do not understand why given that we find the principal value for the first equation and not the second.
My working out is as follows:
For $n \log(z)$:
$5 \log(1+i) = 5 \log \sqrt2 +i\frac{5 \pi}{4} = 5 \log \sqrt2 +i\frac{-3 \pi}{4}$
On the other hand, for $\log(z^n)$:
$\log(\sqrt2 ^5 e^{i\frac{5\pi}{4}}) = \log(\sqrt2 ^5 e^{i\frac{-3\pi}{4}} ) = 5 \log \sqrt2 +i\frac{-3 \pi}{4}$
which means they are equal for the value of $n = 5$ and $z = 1+i$.
Can someone kindly explain what I am overlooking?

$5 \log \sqrt2 +i\frac{5 \pi}{4} = 5 \log \sqrt2 +i\frac{-3 \pi}{4}$ - it's not true, $5 \neq -3$.

Is this the case even though $\theta$ = $\frac{5 \pi}{4}$ and we can get the principal value from this to get $\theta$ = $\frac{-3\pi}{4}$

There is no "principal value of complex number". After you fix branch of logarithm (principal value), $\log(z)$ is just a complex number (unless $z$ is real negative number, then it's not defined).

Thinking about $(1+i)^5=-4(1+i)$ may illustrate the issue.

@mihaild Are you sure that logarithm is not defined for real negative numbers?

@mihaild correct me if i’m wrong but it would be defined for real negative numbers but it’s just not analytic for real negative numbers and y = 0.

It seems that there are conveniently two traditions: Log is multi-valued, log is principal branch with cut on negative reals, and vice-versa Log is principal branch, log is multi-valued. My comments above was assuming the first one. Principal branch isn't defined for non-positve reals, is analytical everywhere else and single-valued. Complex logarithm is defined and analytical everywhere but in $0$, but is multi-valued. Do you write $\log$ for principal branch or complex logarithm? (the identity in title fails for both, but for different reasons)

As explained in mihaild's comment, you are basically claiming that $\frac{5\pi}{4}i=\frac{-3\pi}{4}i$ in your first calculation, which is obviously not true.
(You are misled because in a very related but very different context, $e^{\frac{5\pi}{4}i}=e^{\frac{-3\pi}{4}i}$ is true. But your numbers are not sitting in an exponent any more. That's the point of this exercise I guess.)
